# How to allow setting hotkey in add-on

Tags: python, add-on

Someone just asked [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?411952-Add-on-Set-Dimensions-in-Edit-Mode&p=3137829) about adding a custom hotkey to an add-on that I made a some time ago. This add-on, for some reason, doesn't show any hotkey setup options when you right click on it like most operators show in Blender.

After doing some research, and looking through add-ons that I have made in the past, it appears that registering operators like...

```
bpy.utils.register_class(SomeClassName)
```

...doesn't allow the operator to have the hotkeys, but registering the entire module...

```
bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
```

...does show the hotkey controls.

**Is this intended behavior? Is there anything to do if you don't want to register the entire module like this?**

### Edit:

For the script that I linked to, simply registering the module instead of the operator class does not provide the user with the hotkey controls.

Here are some screenshots showing what I mean in case of any misunderstandings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could not find the evidences that using `bpy.utils.register_module` makes the Add Shortcut button appear. Does not work for 2.79 addons API Navigator or Cloud Generator with prefixes `api_navigator.` and `cloud.`.

Comment: `bpy.utils.register_module` is defined in `2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\utils` and does not seem to do anything with shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An operator represents an action or task that can be performed in blender. A button is blender's GUI representation of an operator which allows the user to initiate the action, while a keyboard shortcut is a non-gui method of executing an operator. Keyboard shortcuts can be edited in the user preferences and each belongs to a group that (*should*) represent the context that it is available. For example, the loop cut operator can be found in the 3DView/Mesh group so is available when editing mesh objects.

When right clicking on a button, the "Change Shortcut" and "Remove Shortcut" menu items are available if the button's operator has a shortcut assigned to it. See [interface_handler.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/interface/interface_handlers.c;e713009e9b83bc7a43443712799c7a24c9dec1cf$6954)

The "Add Shortcut" menu item, represents blender having some idea of what group the shortcut should be added to. Blender "guesses" the group based on the operator's `bl_idname` property and the menu option is only available if a valid group can be guessed from the operator's name. See [wm_keymap.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_keymap.c;e713009e9b83bc7a43443712799c7a24c9dec1cf$1636) where you will find the available group names that can be used. The group names used there are the uppercase version of the first part of the `bl_idname` of the operator with the `_OT` part being optional. For example giving your operator `bl_idname='screen.my_operator'` will enable the add shortcut menu item which will add a shortcut that will be found under "Screen" group in the shortcut settings.

Comment: Hmm...Is it best practice to make the bl_idname `addon_name.operator` or `category.operator` or `category.addon_name.operator`? I have been using the first method to prevent duplicate operator names...

Comment: Actually, it seems that a bl_idname can't have more than 1 "." character...any advice on this?

Comment: @pycoder - `cat.opname` is the general design, so `cat.myop` becomes `bpy.ops.cat.myop` as addon numbers are rising, I think using `addon_name.op_name`is a good idea, particularly for larger addons. If we define shortcuts for operators in each addon then the change shortcut will be available, regardless of operator name. I think consider the add shortcut of limited use - maybe even a builtin operator only feature - unless you can get a dev to change it, maybe add a category choice to the popup when setting the shortcut.

Comment: As unused keys are hard to find, the use of two-key shortcuts will probably start rising, maybe using one two-key combo to get a pie menu for every operator in an addon? If you are unfamiliar with two-key setup, try holding D like a modifier key and press Q. Select stroke editing and try again. Then settings....